# Removing background from the body in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I've been trying to remove the background grey coloured portion above the post title in my Blogger template using CSS. But it just won't go away.

Yes, I'm not very experienced with CSS. If anyone could take a look and help me out, I'll be really grateful. Others like me would also learn a thing or two if you could explain a bit about the solution.

I've attached an image to make things clearer.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Kok.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Anshuman Sinha! Please explain what you have tried so far and where it failed, StackOverflow is not a coding service. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question.

Answer (score 0):

identify the `div` in which the `background-color:grey;` is given then use `!important` to override the color. ex:

```
body{
  background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't just casually use `!important` like Anand suggested.

You'll still have to find what element has the background-color with the inspector. And override the property
However rather then using `!important` it would be best to do it by making your css more specific.

read more about this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity